# Timeout command on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, timeout

Is there an alternative for the timeout command on Mac OSx. The basic requirement is I am able to run a command for a specified amount of time.

e.g:

```
timeout 10 ping google.com
```

This program runs ping for 10s on Linux.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/how-to-introduce-timeout-for-shell-scripting

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You can use

```
brew install coreutils
```

And then whenever you need timeout, use

```
gtimeout
```

..instead. To explain why here's a snippet from the Homebrew Caveats section:

> Caveats
>
> All commands have been installed with the prefix 'g'.
>
> If you really need to use these commands with their normal names, you
>   can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
>
> ```
> PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> Additionally, you can access their man pages with normal names if you add
>   the "gnuman" directory to your MANPATH from your bashrc as well:
>
> ```
> MANPATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH"
> ```

Comment: Then: alias timeout=gtimeout

Comment: Or `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gtimeout /usr/local/bin/timeout` to just enable the one command (the alias solution works for interactive CLI use, but not when called from bash scripts).

Comment: On my side after installed coerutils I got timeout available as time out: ln -s /usr/local/bin/gtimeout /usr/local/bin/timeout
ln: /usr/local/bin/timeout: File exists

Comment: Update: I just installed coreutils using `brew install coreutils`, and the `timeout` command was available without the prefix.

Comment: Great - but I'm nervous about introducing (and then forgetting) about dependencies.  I prefer the perl solution since it's native.

Answer (score 39):

Another simple approach that works pretty much cross platform (because it uses perl which is nearly everywhere) is this:

```
function timeout() { perl -e 'alarm shift; exec @ARGV' "$@"; }
```

Snagged from here:
https://gist.github.com/jaytaylor/6527607

Instead of putting it in a function, you can just put the following line in a script, and it'll work too:

#### timeout.sh

```
perl -e 'alarm shift; exec @ARGV' "$@";
```

or a version that has built in help/examples:

#### timeout.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function show_help()
{
  IT=$(cat <<EOF

Runs a command, and times out if it doesnt complete in time

Example usage:
 
   # Will fail after 1 second, and shows non zero exit code result
   $ timeout 1 "sleep 2" 2> /dev/null ; echo \$?
   142

   # Will succeed, and return exit code of 0.
   $ timeout 1 sleep 0.5; echo \$?
   0

   $ timeout 1 bash -c 'echo "hi" && sleep 2 && echo "bye"' 2> /dev/null; echo \$?
   hi
   142

   $ timeout 3 bash -c 'echo "hi" && sleep 2 && echo "bye"' 2> /dev/null; echo \$?
   hi
   bye
   0
EOF
)
  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  show_help
fi

#
# Mac OS-X does not come with the delightfully useful `timeout` program.  Thankfully a rough BASH equivalent can be achieved with only 2 perl statements.
#
# Originally found on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601543/command-line-command-to-auto-kill-a-command-after-a-certain-amount-of-time
# 
perl -e 'alarm shift; exec @ARGV' "$@";
```

Comment: What does it look like to use it directly, without wrapping it in a function?

Comment: it's pretty much just remove the function and leave the perl line... I put more details above!

Comment: What does it look like as a single-use one-liner?  Something like `perl -e 'alarm shift; exec "ping google.com"`?

Comment: Unfortunately this generates an `Alarm clock` message when the timer expires, and eliminating this [gets messy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104918/17681).

Comment: Hey... Did you try it like in the examples I showed? You can ignore the alarm clock message by running it like so: `./timeout.sh 1 "sleep 2.5" 2> /dev/null; echo $?`. Note that you can also capture the output if you're running it in a subshell like so:  `RESULT=$(./timeout.sh 1 "sleep 2.5" 2> /dev/null; echo $?)
`

Comment: Would be good to add the ualarm version for when you need more precision: 

`function timeout() { perl -e 'use Time::HiRes "ualarm"; ualarm shift; exec @ARGV' "$@"; }` 

(Note that it requires Perl >= 5.8 according to http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html)

Comment: @BradParks When I use this, I get an "Alarm clock" message output to `stderr`. Some quick searches suggest this is the shell's response to seeing a SIGALARM, not something that's actually output by `perl`. Any suggestions on how to suppress this (without ALSO suppressing all `stderr` from the script being run with a timeout)?

Answer (score 28):

As [kvz stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21118126/4964553) simply use homebrew:

```
brew install coreutils
```

**Now the `timeout` command is already ready to use** - no aliases are required (and no `gtimeout` required, although also available).

Comment: Thanks for the comment about an alias not being necessary. `which timeout # /usr/local/bin/timeout` indeed.

Answer (score 10):

You can limit execution time of any program using this command:

```
ping -t 10 google.com & sleep 5; kill $!
```

Comment: This is probably not what you want. The result is that the command will run exactly 5 seconds. Meaning, if you want it to be a max time but not also the min this is not what you are looking for

Comment: I didn't understand what @gesell was saying at first.  But after running this command:  ` ping -t 1 google.com & sleep 5; kill $!` I realized what he/she meant:  The _entire_ expression is going to take exactly 5 seconds before terminating.  However, this is the solution I chose because I was running a bash command from a python program in background thread - so as long as it terminated sometime I was happy.

Answer (score 3):

The Timeout Package from Ubuntu / Debian can be made to compile on Mac and it works.
The package is available at http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/timeout

Comment: An easier way is to use Homebrew: `brew install coreutils` - then use `gtimeout` or set your PATH to use the `timeout` name.

Comment: As of Ubuntu 20.04, there doesn't appear to be a separate `timeout` package. The `timeout` command is provided by `coreutils`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `ping -t 10 google.com >nul`

the >nul gets rid of the output. So instead of showing 64 BYTES FROM 123.45.67.8 BLAH BLAH BLAH it'll just show a blank newline until it times out. -t flag can be changed to any number.

Comment: Ping was really a sample. I want to run a program to collect some metrics

Comment: `>nul` is a Windows thing. On macOS this would literally create a file called `nul` and redirect output to it