# how to decrease ssh connection timeout value

Tags: bash, networking, ssh, timeout, client

I have a list of full remote host ip addresses. I wrote a script to connect all the hosts in this list, one by one. My question is, sometimes when an IP address is down, script waits for a while (maybe a couple of minute) to go and execute next host. So I would like to decrease this waiting time. For example after 10 s, I want ssh connection is timeout and my script tries the next IP address. So how I can tweak this?

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How to setup SSH timeout in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936807/how-to-setup-ssh-timeout-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

if you call ssh script you can use something like that

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10  <hostName>
```

where 10 is the number of seconds

Comment: Actually I try to do something like:

ssh-keygen
for HOST in $(cat /scripts/ip_list); do
        ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ${HOST}
done



So I don't know where I can use -o option.  I can try something like
[code]
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh  -o  ConnectTimeout=10 username@${HOST} 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'

but the thing is, some of these remote home directories don't have a ~/.ssh folder. So command will fail when it couldn't find ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: how to add milliseconds value to timeout ?

Comment: As far as I know, `ssh` option `ConnectTimeout` has granularity of 1 second and minimum you can use is 1 second. I agree that for local network connections setting timeout to say 50-100 ms could make sense. If you need to rapidly connect to other servers, see settings `ControlMaster`, `ControlPath` and set `ControlPersist 1`.