# How to ignore or Pass 'Yes' when The authenticity of host can't be established in Expect Shell script during Automation

Tags: shell, automation, rsa, expect, host

I want to Provide 'Yes' automatically or Ignore it and proceed in a SECURE way, when the below statement comes during execution of my Expect Shell script?.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh $user@$host
```

> The authenticity of host 'abcdef (10.566.1.98)' can't be established.
>   RSA key fingerprint is jk:94:ba:93:0b:eb:ff:df:ea:gh:hj:23:3c:hj:9c:be.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Comment: "secure" and expect don't usually go hand-in-hand. There is no guaranteed way if you are automatically accepting the RSA fingerprint to know that it is legitimate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force ssh to accept a new host fingerprint from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383806/how-can-i-force-ssh-to-accept-a-new-host-fingerprint-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of `exp_continue` for this scenario.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect 
set prompt "#|>|\\\$"
spawn ssh dinesh@myhost
expect {
        #If 'expect' sees '(yes/no )', then it will send 'yes'
        #and continue the 'expect' loop
        "(yes/no)" { send "yes\r";exp_continue}
        #If 'password' seen first, then proceed as such.
        "password"
}
send "root\r"
expect -re $prompt
```

Reference : [Expect](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html)

Comment: Thanks Dinesh!!..It worked perfectly!..But i dint Set the prompt and the final command expect -re $Prompt..It worked without those!

Answer (score 41):

It's possible to avoid this question and accept all incoming keys automaticatilly by using ssh client option `StrictHostKeyChecking` set to `no` (default setting is `ask`, which results in that question):

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$user@$host"
```

However, note that it would be hardly any secure, as you're basically accepting connect with everyone who may act as a given host. The only secure way to avoid question is to pre-distribute host public keys to clients, i.e. in form of pre-generated known hosts file, which can be used in some way like that:

```
ssh \
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=PATH_TO_YOUR_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes "$user@$host"
```

This way you'll avoid the question if the check fails, and ssh will result in non-zero exit status.

Comment: +1.  yup, another case where the accepted answer lags behind...  You can set `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` in your **~/.ssh/config** on a per-host basis.

Comment: @JLPeyret If you know your hosts beforehand and are willing to set up them individually, then you might just as well set up proper keys for them?

Comment: chef-based auto installs. i'd have to prepolute known_hosts.  risk is low, it's a git fetch against a low privilege git user. everything's set up correctly, AFAIK, but it's not a known host, on the being-installed machine,  yet when chef runs

Comment: actually, while I liked your answer, I only looked at part #1, and didn't really realize what you meant with part #2.  I'll check into it, looks even better.

Answer (score 13):

This works, and it's especially convenient for docker builds

```sh
ssh-keyscan hostname.example.com >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver, thank you! This should be the accepted answer, it's quicker and more convenient.