# Circle CI how to deploy to ssh - error The authenticity can't be established

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, circleci

I would like to deploy my code into my server using SSH.

I add ssh key to circle ci settings.

In circle ci pipeline I have code...

`scp -q -r /build root@XXXXXXXX:/root/test`

problem is, that I have `The authenticity of host 'XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXX )' can't be established.` message. How can I skip it or confirm it?

```
scp -q -r /build root@XXXXXXXX:/root/test
The authenticity of host 'XXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXX )' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:6+xxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

How can I respond to the prompt in a circle ci pipeline job? It is running somewhere on some server.

Comment: Expect will help you out here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461713/how-to-ignore-or-pass-yes-when-the-authenticity-of-host-cant-be-established-i

Comment: Use this option https://stackoverflow.com/a/28469910/7822767

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for option `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. Below code should do this.
`scp -q -r -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /build root@XXXXXXXX:/root/test`