# How to skip fingerprint checking when "sudo ssh localhost"?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-20.04

When first enter a `sudo ssh localhost` we always get a note like:

> The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:u0q6ow7gfu4IvqfGOytZB6MKjO479AUr9hulSqO/dy4.
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?

And I want to skip this step.

I have try follow(with sshpass):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/deploy_rsa<<<y
cat ~/.ssh/deploy_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo ssh-keyscan localhost>>~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Well it seems just works in `ssh localhost`, but not in `sudo ssh localhost`.
So is there any reliable way to access my goal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore or Pass 'Yes' when The authenticity of host can't be established in Expect Shell script during Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461713/how-to-ignore-or-pass-yes-when-the-authenticity-of-host-cant-be-established-i)

Comment: Why are you using `sudo ssh localhost` (and `sudo ssh-keyscan`)? It doesn't accomplish anything better than `ssh root@localhost` and in this case worse.

Comment: For some reason, I have to run a python script in `sudo` and use ansible-playbook 
to localhost in it to finish some job...So I post my question here.

Answer (score 3):

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no localhost`

Or for something more permanent, create or modify your `~/.ssh/config` with this:

```
Host localhost
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Also you should know that this process opens you up to MITM attacks (not on `localhost` obviously) and shouldn't be done on any important server.