# How to pass a known fingerprint to SSH (in order to avoid the manual prompt)

Tags: ssh

How do I pass a known fingerprint (such as `SHA256:BcOkb1S0zuj5A1CDxpOSuD2hnAArV1A3wKY7iOlks`) to SSH, so that I don't need to manually answer the prompt?

I tried the following, which does not seem to work:

```
ssh some-user@my-domain.com <<EOF
SHA256:BcOkb1S0zuj5A1CDxpOSuD2hnAArV1A3wKY7iOlks
EOF
```

Comment: take a look here, I don't think there is any other way [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383806/how-can-i-force-ssh-to-accept-a-new-host-fingerprint-from-the-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383806/how-can-i-force-ssh-to-accept-a-new-host-fingerprint-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @Tch - Thanks. Unfortunately, all those solutions are prone to MITM attacks.

Comment: You could prepare the complete entry and then copy it to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. The entry should look like `my-domain.com ssh-rsa AAEFB...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the comment "You could prepare the complete entry and then copy it to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file.", that preparation would be done [using `ssh-keyscan`](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-easily-add-an-ssh-fingerprint-to-your-knownhosts-file-in-linux/):

```sh
ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.1.162 
# or
ssh-keyscan my-domain.com
```

If you have a known fingerprint, you can also double-check it, if [is still valid](https://serverfault.com/a/1002348/783).

Comment: Thnaks for the link to [validate a fingerprint](https://serverfault.com/a/1002348/783), that was the missing piece for me

Comment: Yes, the additional validation of the fingerprint makes this answer complete (the use of ssh-keyscan alone being prone to MITM attacks).