# Failed next js application to vercel and unkown git error from tradingview/charting_library

Tags: git, github, next.js, deployment, vercel

i tried deploying my next js application to vercel and i got this errors. npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/tradingview/charting_library.git
npm ERR! command-line line 0: unsupported option "accept-new".
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-02-29T15_57_22_754Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 128
why am i getting this error and how can i fix it so my application can be deployed sucessfully.

i was told to add ssh keys to my github so i added it, i uninstalled and reinstalled node modules but it isn't still working

Comment: `accept-new` is [an SSH option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61946687/7976758) but it seems it's not supported at Vercel. I'm not sure you can fix it at your side. Write a bug report at Vercel.