# Bash How to kill wget process after a given timeout?

Tags: bash

UPDATE:

This question has been closed. I asked in another question.
[Bash how to run multiple wget with output by sequence (NOT Parallel) and delete the wget file for speedtest purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445432/bash-how-to-run-multiple-wget-with-output-by-sequence-not-parallel-and-delete)

I used timeout solution

```
#!/bin/bash

function speedtest() {

    local key=$1
    local url=$2

    timeout 10 wget $url
    echo -e "\033[40;32;1m$key is completed.\033[0m"

 
}

speedtest "Lisbon" "https://lg-lis.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip"
speedtest "London" "https://lg-lon.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip"
speedtest "Madrid" "https://lg-mad.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip"
speedtest "Paris" "https://lg-par2.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip"
```

When I run the bash script, this is the output.

```
» ./wget_speedtest.sh                                                                                       [2021/05/8 |15:42:49]

Redirecting output to ‘wget-log’.
Lisbon is completed.

Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.1’.
London is completed.

Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.2’.
Madrid is completed.

Redirecting output to ‘wget-log.3’.
Paris is completed.
```

I am expected to see the kb/s for running after 10 seconds for each wget.

---

I have a list of wget of file to download and want to see the download speed. I just want to run about 10 seconds, then print out the result what is the download speed.
I have 20 different server file to test out. My goal is to see the how kb/s download for that 10 seconds.

e.g

```
> wget https://lg-lis.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip                                                          
--2021-05-08 13:37:37--  https://lg-lis.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip
Resolving lg-lis.fdcservers.net (lg-lis.fdcservers.net)... 50.7.43.4
Connecting to lg-lis.fdcservers.net (lg-lis.fdcservers.net)|50.7.43.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 104857600 (100M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘100MBtest.zip’

100MBtest.zip                      0%[                                                         ] 679.66K   174KB/s    eta 9m 26s ^C
```

This is my bash file

```
#!/bin/bash

function speedtest() {

    local key=$1
    local url=$2

     ( cmdpid=$$; 
     (sleep 10; kill $cmdpid; rm -f 100M) \
        & while ! wget "$url"
      do 
          echo -e "\033[40;32;1m$key for 10 seconds done.\033[0m"
      done )

 
}
speedtest "Lisbon" "https://lg-lis.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip"
speedtest "London" "https://lg-lon.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip"
speedtest "Madrid" "https://lg-mad.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip"
speedtest "Paris" "https://lg-par2.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip"
```

However, the above code does not work, it still download at background and redirect to wget-log

```
> ./wget_speedtest.sh                                                                                       
--2021-05-08 13:41:56--  https://lg-lis.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip
Resolving lg-lis.fdcservers.net (lg-lis.fdcservers.net)... 50.7.43.4
Connecting to lg-lis.fdcservers.net (lg-lis.fdcservers.net)|50.7.43.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 104857600 (100M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘100M’

100M                             5%[==>                                                      ]   5.84M  1.02MB/s    eta 79s    [1]    21251 terminated  ./wget_speedtest.sh

Redirecting output to ‘wget-log’.
```

Comment: I am asking the bash script to run multiple wget, it is not about just the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `timeout` command (part of GNU coreutils):

```
$ timeout 10 wget https://lg-lis.fdcservers.net
/100MBtest.zip
--2021-05-07 22:53:20--  https://lg-lis.fdcservers.net/100MBtest.zip
Resolving lg-lis.fdcservers.net (lg-lis.fdcservers.net)... 50.7.43.4
Connecting to lg-lis.fdcservers.net (lg-lis.fdcservers.net)|50.7.43.4|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 104857600 (100M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘100MBtest.zip’

100MBtest.zip         0%[                    ]  23.66K  10.8KB/s               
$
```

If the specified time is exceeded, `timeout` exits with a status of 124.

`timeout --help` or `info coreutils timeout` for more information.

If you're on MacOS, see [Timeout command on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3504945/827263) for some suggested alternatives.

Comment: I am using MacOS, but I wish this bash script able to work in UNIX system. So I hope not install extra package. and need to run in bash script for multiple link

Comment: Then write a C program.

Comment: @Shiro https://stackoverflow.com/q/3504945/827263

Comment: I install gtimeout, however, I still want it in the bash script so I no need rerun it. I update in my question for using the gtimeout