# bash script kill command after timeout

Tags: linux, bash, runtime, compilation, kill

I have bash script that work for many files in loop. It compiles, check the result etc.
Now I'd like to make a security in case of infinity loop inside of one of thouse files. something like:
If it's not done after 5 min. Kill the process and gave info about that.

```
gcc -Wall -o "${FN}_execute" ${FN} 2> ${FN}_c_compilation.txt
./${FN}_execute $PARAM > ${FN}_c_result.txt
```

How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command line command to auto-kill a command after a certain amount of time.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601543/command-line-command-to-auto-kill-a-command-after-a-certain-amount-of-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at:

http://www.bashcookbook.com/bashinfo/source/bash-4.0/examples/scripts/timeout3

Answer (score 0):

You could record the start time (in seconds) and just check if the current time (in seconds) is more than 300.

But why are you writing a script to compile files manually? Doesn't `make` do what you want?