# Limiting processes to 0.5s in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How can I limit processes to less than 1s CPU time in Bash? I am using version 4.1.5(1) and if I type `ulimit -t 0.5 command`, I get:

```
-bash: ulimit: 0.5: invalid number
```

I am using `ulimit -t 1 command` as an imperfect substitute, but for technical reasons I don't need to bother you with, I would very much like `command` to be stopped after it has had CPU for a half-second or maybe a bit less.

A Linux-specific answer would be fine.

Comment: I forgot to say this was in the context of programming a shell script in Bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other people said, you can't do it with the standard built-in Bash commands.

It is possible to create your own command to limit the elapsed time for a command (distinct from the actual CPU time used by the command; see also the comments from [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8747/rob), for which, thanks!).  I've previously published on SO [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601543/command-line-command-to-auto-kill-a-command-after-a-certain-amount-of-time/) to do timeouts after an integer number of elapsed seconds (so it is not directly an answer to your problem).  However, you could (fairly) easily adapt the code to use sub-second resolution on the elapsed time and the POSIX facilities.  The core interface is:

```
timeout -t time [-s signal] cmd [args ...]
```

To handle your requirements, it would simply need to recognize sub-second times and call the appropriate functions; it affects the internals far more than the externals.

Theoretically (according to POSIX 2008), you should use the [`timer_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_create.html), [`timer_settime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_gettime.html) and `timer_gettime()` functions.  These provide detailed control over which signal should be generated when the timer expires, etc.  However, not all systems provide them (for example, MacOS X 10.6.7 does not document them).  These use the headers `<time.h>` and `<signal.h>`, and `struct itimerspec` (and `struct sigevent`).

However, in the short term, you may need to use the functions [`getitimer()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getitimer.html) and `setitimer()` instead, which POSIX 2008 marks as obsolescent (but which are available on MacOS X 10.6.7).  These use the header `<sys/time.h>` and `struct itimerval`.

To be portable, you may need to autoconfigure your program to deal with both these; you might also need to deal with Windows (which will undoubtedly provide an alternative interface).  You probably fall back on `alarm()` and whole-second granularity timing if neither of the fine resolution signalling timer systems is available.  Choose the `timer_*` functions over the `*itimer` functions if both are present - or simply test for `timer_*` first and use them if available.

Be aware that if you set a timeout of 0.5 seconds with these functions, they guarantee a minimum elapsed time of 0.5 seconds - but it may be arbitrarily longer than the time because of scheduling issues.  Note that there is a `timer_getoverrun()` to help establish how long the overrun was.

Comment: This solution seems to signal after a fixed elapsed time, not a fixed CPU time. The OP asked for a sginal after 0.5 s of CPU time.

Comment: @Rob: I want to fly to the moon tomorrow - sadly, it isn't currently feasible.  The elapsed time is the best approximation to CPU time that's available at sub-second accuracy.

Comment: **I** know that. **You** know that. But your answer doesn't make that clear to the OP.  P.s. A link to your [previously-published SO code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601543/command-line-command-to-auto-kill-a-command-after-a-certain-amount-of-time/601576#601576) would have been helpful.

Comment: Indeed, while I can work with wall clock time, which is a close approximation of process time for my application and can only be larger in any case, I didn't realize that I would be making this approximation until I saw Rob's comment. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can't. The underlying system call ([`setrlimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)) provides only whole-second resolution.

```
 RLIMIT_CPU
          CPU time limit in seconds.  When the process  reaches  the  soft
          limit, it is sent a SIGXCPU signal.  The default action for this
          signal is to terminate the process.  However, the signal can  be
          caught,  and the handler can return control to the main program.
          If the process continues to consume CPU time, it  will  be  sent
          SIGXCPU  once  per  second  until  the hard limit is reached, at
          which time it is sent SIGKILL.
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. The underlying [setrlimit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) call has a granularity of seconds.