# Bash script that kills a output redirection after a period of time

Tags: bash, timeout, kill

I'm looking for a lightweight solution to kill a command with output redirection if it hangs. my current solution

```
if [[ -w /tmp/mypipe ]]; then
  timeout --kill-after 10 5 echo "1" > /tmp/mypipe
fi
```

works only if the left part of the command does not work correctly (e.g. no one does read from the pipe). But I discovered situation, where the redirection hangs -- which at least are an issue of not completely synchronized tasks, which I can't solve now.

There are several related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/bash-script-that-kills-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224939/bash-run-a-process-for-limited-time-period?lq=1) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851889/kill-process-after-a-given-time-bash). The last one mostly covers my question, but I'm still looking for a more slim solution. It suggests to work like

```
( CMDPID=$BASHPID; \
  (sleep 5; kill -9 $CMDPID >& /dev/null) & echo "1" > /tmp/mypipe )
```

But this spawns two new bash processes. Is there a more lightweight solution for that problem?

Comment: Why must it be lightweight? Do you have a problem with too many bash processes running?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that each spawned bash process will share the vast majority of its memory with the parent process, so it's not tripling memory usage like top would have you believe.

If you still want to try to optimize, `timeout 5 tee /tmp/mypipe <<< "1" > /dev/null` will spawn a timeout and a tee process instead.

Comment: Well, thanks for the input. I really did not think about the implicit efficiency of the process management. If I find the time, I will try your solution as well.