# How can you handle retryCountOnTaskFailure and timeoutInMinutes together?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a database dumping script

```yaml
- bash: |
    ./dump-db.sh 
  displayName: "Dump RDS"
  timeoutInMinutes: "10"
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: 3
```

Which on occassion takes too long so I want it to timeout and retry.  However, it seems that if the timeout triggers the retry no longer fires.  It seems that `timeoutInMinutes` takes a higher precedence.  This is with agent version 2.200.2.

There's a [community feedback that is closed on this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/retrycountontaskfailure-and-timeoutinminutes-dont/1631825)

So what I am thinking is to create a template that will do the dump and run for 10 minutes and have it retry three times on something that calls the template.

Answer (score 0):

I use [`timeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7859452/242042) which is available in the Azure DevOps ubuntu agents to handle the timeouts

```yaml
- bash: |
    timeout 600 ./dump-db.sh 
  displayName: "Dump RDS"
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: 3
```