# How to execute strace for a particular time period

Tags: android, shell, execute, strace

I'm logging the system call execution associated with an Android app using 'strace' command.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
OutputStream os;
os = process.getOutputStream();
os.write("strace -p"+processID+" -o /mnt/sdcard/straceLog.txt".getBytes());
os.close();
```

How can I strace the system calls only for a particular time period for any application(say 30 seconds) and interrupt the strace execution after that..Please help...

Comment: strace (at least the Android version) does not appear to have any such options.  Possibilities might be running a timer in your java app and killing the strace (or parent superuser shell) after a while, or building a modified strace with a time limit.  You could also consider capturing the output in java and then closing the pipe once you have as much as you want, and seeing if that causes strace to die on an EPIPE as a result of your end closing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `timeout` program.

`timeout 1 strace -c sleep 5`

Or incorporated into the OP's question:

`os.write("timeout 30 strace -p"+processID+" -o /mnt/sdcard/straceLog.txt".getBytes());`

This *might* not be available on Android (I don't know), however this issue was the first hit when I searched for running strace time based, so hope this can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Run strace in a background process and kill the process after a given amount of time.

[Command line command to auto-kill a command after a certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601543/command-line-command-to-auto-kill-a-command-after-a-certain-amount-of-time#637753)

os.write("strace -p"+processID+" -o /mnt/sdcard/straceLog.txt & sleep 30; kill $!".getBytes());