# PhantomJS hanging during page load - has anyone found a workaround?

Tags: phantomjs

PhantomJS is having an intermittent problem completing page loads for me.

The last thing I see in the output from `--debug=true` is

`2015-03-21T21:26:39 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 86`

Other people have noticed similar-sounding issues as well:

- https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11526
- https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10652
- https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12234

My question for the SO community is -- has anyone found a good workaround or identified what might be triggering this condition in the page load?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same problem using phantomjs in an R script and finally found a workaround. See the comment from vasi on this page:

[Command line command to auto-kill a command after a certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601543/command-line-command-to-auto-kill-a-command-after-a-certain-amount-of-time)

Where he/she gives this bit of command line perl code that will allow you to kill the phantomjs process if it doesn't complete after a given amount of time.

```
perl -e '$s = shift; $SIG{ALRM} = sub { print STDERR "Timeout!\n"; kill INT => $p }; exec(@ARGV) unless $p = fork; alarm $s; waitpid $p, 0' 10 phantomjs file.js
```