# How to put execution time limit on g++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I use the following to compile my C++ Program.

`g++ filename.cpp -o filename.o`

Then I take an input file and direct the output to the another file.

`filename.o < in.txt > out.txt`

However sometimes the code goes into an infinite loop and I am not able to stop it (I force quit the `.o` from Activity Monitor).

What is want it to put an execution limit time on the program so that after it it automatically stops executing. Is there any way to this?

Something like:- `g++ filename.cpp -o filename.o [execution_limit_here=10.0s]`

Edit:- I am creating an Atom Package and users will compile and execute their code for a particular set of input files, using a simple key combination.

So I can’t predict beforehand if the code will go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line command to auto-kill a command after a certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601543/command-line-command-to-auto-kill-a-command-after-a-certain-amount-of-time)

Comment: **TL;DR**: check out GNU coreutils' [`timeout`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) utility (also on OS X via Homebrew)

Comment: There's a significant difference between slow and infinite! I'd suggest you eliminate the latter as a logical possibility.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> g++ filename.cpp -o filename.o
> ```

Very bad taste (even if it could work). By *convention* `*.o` files are [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file), not executables, but in your compilation command, the `fileno.o` is the [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) output (i.e. produced by `g++`) by compilation and linking. Read about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

I guess you are on Linux or POSIX (e.g. MacOSX, Android...)

I recommend

```
  g++ -Wall -Wextra -g filename.cpp -o filename
```

In that command, we ask for all warnings and debug info, and the executable is named `filename` (without a confusing `.o` suffix).

Standard C++ does not know about time limits, but POSIX (so Linux and MacOSX) does, and I recommend using [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_CPU`. That should be coded in the application (you could call `setrlimit` early in your `main`).

Otherwise, code a shell like program (or use some shell script [with `ulimit`](https://superuser.com/questions/220059/what-parameters-does-ulimit-have)) to run your executable with some CPU limit and/or use [timeout(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html).

See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) to understand the various notions of time.

But **you really should debug your program** ([using the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand its behavior) **to *always* avoid infinite loops**. Perhaps you could use some timer facilities (e.g. [setitimer(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) and catch the `SIGALRM` [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html); read also [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)) and/or query in your loops the elapsed real or CPU time (and check it against some threshold).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I am using MacOS. Could you please explain why `g++ filename.cpp -o filename.o` is bad taste? And how second command is better? Also I am creating an Atom Package(see my edit) so GNU `coreutils` will get the job done for now.

Comment: I did explain that `.o` is the conventional suffix for object files.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd recommend putting printouts on your program so you can figure out why it's getting stuck in an infinite loop, and if you only want to have a time limit you could set a starting time with clock() (from ctime) and after each iteration compare the current time with the starting time point.

Comment: What about passing the running time as an argument at execution time? (At command line?)

Answer (score 1):

You could use timeout command while running the executable command

```sh
timeout 5 ./a.out
```

This command will only run the given command (in this case executable) for 5 seconds